# What is the motivation/applications for the definition of Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, motivation

The definition of the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^n$ is fundamentally tied up with the following assumption:

> The measure of the cartesian product of $n$ intervals should be the product of the lengths of those intervals.

That is to say, to define measure on $\mathbb R^n$, we just blindly generalize the formula for the area of a rectangle or the volume of a cuboid. Why do this?

Cartesian products of intervals, and the concept of multiplying their lengths together, are only relevant in $\mathbb R^2$ and $\mathbb R^3$. In fact, even there, they're only relevant when those sets are being interpreted as models for physical space. If I was working on a two-variable problem in which the variables were temperature and pressure, then measuring the "size" of the set of all configurations with temperature in $[0, 2]$ and pressure in $[5, 3]$ (say) by multiplying together $|2-0|$ and $|5-3|$ would seem like a very irrelevant thing to do. And if I'm working on an $n$-variable problem, then claiming that this operation could possibly provide a useful notion of the "size" of a set just seems absurd.

Comment: So we can integrate weird functions.

Comment: @Nameless If all you wanted was *some* definition that would allow you to integrate weird functions, I've got you covered. Define $\int f=0$ for all $f$. We don't just pick definitions because they work, we pick them because they mean something.

Comment: @JackM You want to integrate functions in a meaningfull way, Jack. Don't be obtuse!

Comment: @PedroTamaroff But my point is that the usual definition does *not* appear to be meaningful. The fact that it happens to generalize a formula that means something in a very specific context doesn't make it meaningful.

Comment: @JackM One has a very clear understanding of what an $n$-dimensional *volume* is for simple figures, like squares, cubes, triangles, tetrahedrons. The Lebesgue measure extends our "measure" to more complicated sets, and gives great technical properties to work with. It is not clear what you mean by "meaningful."

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Well, maybe what I should be asking for are applications.

Comment: If you want motivation for the "product rule", just look say at Fubini's theorem. I bet you've encountered already.

Comment: You can define a measure to be anything you want as long as it satisfies the axioms. This happens to be one particular definition, the Lebesgue Measure. If you think there is something better and more "intuitive", then please be my guest.

Comment: For applications, go into probability.

Comment: @Nameless If you have time, could you be more specific in an answer?

Comment: @JackM, https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL17567A1A3F5DB5E4 try these.

Answer (score 4):

You want to develop the Lebesgue integral in a way which generalises the Riemann integral. In order to do that, you need to specify the Lebesgue measure. Regardless of how you want to define Lebesgue measure $m$, for any set $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ that you want to measure, it should satisfy

$$m(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_A dm$$

where the integral on the right is the Lebesgue integral of the characteristic function of $A$. But hold on, if we're pretending like we don't have the Lebesgue measure at our disposal, what does the Lebesgue integral even mean? Well, all I've said about it so far is that is *should* generalise the Riemann integral, at least for nice functions.

Now consider $A = [a_1, b_1]\times\dots\times[a_n, b_n] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. This is a pretty reasonable set (it's a Borel set after all), so you would hope that the Lebesgue measure of this set is defined. Furthermore, $\chi_A$ is a reasonable function (it is Riemann integrable), so you'd hope that you can make sense of its Lebesgue integral. But if we want the Lebesgue integral to generalise the Riemann integral, they should give the same number. That is,

$$m(A) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_A dm = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_A dx.$$

But we know how to evaluate the last integral:

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\chi_A dx = \int_{a_n}^{b_n}\dots\int_{a_1}^{b_1}1dx_1\dots dx_n = (b_1 - a_1)\dots(b_n - a_n).$$

So defining $m([a_1, b_1]\times\dots\times[a_n, b_n]) = (b_1 - a_1)\dots(b_n - a_n)$ seems pretty reasonable if you want the Lebesgue integral to generalise the Riemann integral.

Comment: But surely at some point in defining an $n$-variable Riemann integral, we're going to use the "assumption" that the "product of the sides" formula is a good way of assigning a size to a cartesian product of intervals, no? So the very thing we're trying to justify seems to be hidden in the details.

Comment: Your assumption that we don't make definitions so that they "work" nicely is just wrong. Mathematicians do this all the time.

Comment: @JackM: I didn't really address that, true. However, you believe that the area of $[a_1, b_1]\times[a_2, b_2]$ is given by $\int_{[a_1, b_1]}(b_2 - a_2)dx$, and that the volume of $[a_1, b_1]\times[a_2, b_2]\times[a_3, b_3]$ is given by $\int_{[a_1, b_1]\times[a_2, b_2]}(b_3 - a_3)dA$. Agreed?

Comment: Yes, agreed.${}{}$

Comment: @JackM I'm curious about your objection to defining the n-volume of rectangles in the obvious way. It seems natural and obvious to most people, but I sense that you have some underlying concern in that regard. Am I understanding that correctly?

Comment: So once you make sense of the length of integral, you can determine area by integrating the height over the base. Now that you know what the area of a rectangle is, you can determine the volume of a cuboid by integrating the height over the rectangular base. Now that you know the volume of a cuboid, why can't you determine the hypervolume of a four-dimensional cuboid by integrating its height over the base cuboid? Mathematically, there's almost no difference between these constructions. Sure, there may be geometric intuition behind the first two, but that doesn't invalidate the mathematics.

Comment: @user4894 Yes. The formula is relevant in $2$ and $3$ dimensions only because it provides the answer to problems like "how much water will I need to fill this box" or "how much canvas will I need to cover this frame" (I'm not saying mathematics has to be practical, I'm just saying that area and volume are inherently physical notions). I can't fathom why you would want to generalize it to $n$ dimensions, or even why anyone is so sure there *should be* a useful generalization of the idea to $n$ dimensions.

Comment: @JackM: Why does the formula for area make sense? Why does the formula for volume make sense? You need to define what a unit of area or volume is. If you do that by saying it is a product of unit lengths, then the normal formulae work. Likewise, in $n$ dimensions, you need to define what a unit of $n$-dimensional volume is. If you define this to be a product of unit lengths as you did in dimensions $2$ and $3$, then the formula for the volume of a cuboid is as given.

Comment: @JackM Is your objection fundamentally to $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself? In other words since there's no obvious physical analog, we shouldn't try to say something sensible about it? Else why not believe in n-rectangles?

Comment: @JackM In any event modern physics uses lots of dimensions, 26 in string theory I hear. Do you believe in rectangles in any dimension that physicists need? I'm not understanding your limitation to 2 and 3 dimensions, physics is way beyond that these days.

Comment: @user4894 $n$-dimenional space is clearly useful in any situation in which we have $n$ real number variables, but what I object to is the general apparent assumption in mathematics that notions that are useful when $n=2,3$ and the variables are coordinates in physical space will automatically be useful in the general case.